# Multiple asset directories in Middleman project

Tags: assets, middleman

I have several microsites, each with its own stylesheet assets, within a larger Middleman project like so:

```
project/
  source/
    microsite1.com/
      stylesheets/
      index.haml
    microsite2.com/
      stylesheets/
      index.haml
    stylesheets/
    index.haml
  config.rb
```

Now, in production, each microsite is accessed via a domain root, e.g. `http://microsite1.com/`. But the above directory structure is what's required by my webhost to manage these microsites, so in development it's ideal to access these at `http://localhost:4567/microsite1.com/`.

However, the paths that asset helpers output aren't relative. For example, in `microsite1.com/index.haml`:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "screen"
```

yields

```
<link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

with :relative_assets unset, and yields

```
<link href="../stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

with it set. The former output is correct in the production case; the latter is correct in neither production nor development.

Is there a way to configure Middleman so that I can test at `http://localhost:4567/microsite1.com/`? Alternatively, is there some way I can simulate `http://microsite1.com/`? (I thought to try modifying `/etc/hosts`, though that doesn't seem to work since I'm not pointing at an IP address)

Comment: `/source/microsite1.com/microsite1.css.scss` is correctly transformed into `/build/microsite1.com/stylesheets/microsite1.css` for me when `middleman build` is invoked. The `css_dir` setting is only crucial if you're using asset helpers, or am I wrong?

Comment: I seem to have gotten some configurations mixed up; I was using "stylesheets" in some places and "sass" in others, which seems to be what was grunking up `middleman build`. I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my hacky but actually pretty functional solution:

```
# microsite1.com/index.haml
- if development? then $asset_base = "/microsite1.com" end

# config.rb
configure :development do
  helpers do
    alias_method :original_asset_path, :asset_path
    def asset_path(*args)
      path = original_asset_path(*args)
      if not path =~ ABSOLUTE_URL_PATTERN && defined? $asset_base
        path = File.join($asset_base, path)
      end
      path
    end
  end
end
```

tl;dr I'm hooking `asset_path` to guarantee that all relative assets (stylesheets, javascripts, images) are prefixed with some `$asset_base` path if specified. (If someone better at Ruby + Middleman than me wants to advise how I might do this without a global variable, I'm all ears.)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to touch the `css_dir` setting at all? You should be able to use the `stylesheet_link_tag` helper as follows ...

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "../microsite1.com/stylesheets/microsite1" %>
```

... within your templates residing in `source/microsite1.com`. This should give you ...

```
<link href="/stylesheets/../microsite1.com/stylesheets/microsite1.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: This solves the problem when testing, but then breaks things again when the microsites are deployed to their final homes (e.g. `http://microsite1.com`); it's also not particularly scalable. I've updated the question to be a bit more precise, and I've included how I've solved it in a more general way